# Where do I ask a question about the use of Messenger on an Android phone?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I need to know the proper place to ask the following question:

> In Messenger mobile for Android some emojis, when posted as the only
> character in a message, explode into a burst of floating emojis that
> flood the sender's and receiver's message area.  The 'Kissy face'
> emoji and the red 'Heart' emoji do this.  What is that behavior called
> and are there other emojis that have similar behavior when posted?

Comment: There is an [Android site](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

## [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/)

Q&A for enthusiasts and power users of the Android operating system

[image]

Searching for [emojis messeger](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=emojis+messager) returns 38 results

Resources

- https://stackexchange.com/sites